# what do variables after options in fmincon stand for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I looked for the definition of `fmincon` in Matworkds and tried to convert my `fmincon` matlab function to a similar python function using `from scipy.optimize import least_squares`

As it's mentioned in the `optimset` function, my python solver will need the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm. Then I guess `last_squares` is the right choice.

Although, as it's mentioned in the `optimset` function, my python solver will need the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm. Then I guess `last_squares` is the right choice.

```
function [alpha,beta,lambda,gamma,c,fX,yhat,ehat,G]=parestlm(y,X,W,q,T,nX,nW,m,gamma,c)

% Compute starting values
% -----------------------
[alpha,beta,lambda,gamma,c] = startval(y,X,W,q,m,gamma,c);
PSI = setpar(gamma,c);

options = optimset('Display','off','Jacobian','on','MaxFunEvals',1e10,...
        'LargeScale','off','MaxIter',4000,'TolFun',1e-10,...
        'DerivativeCheck','off','LevenbergMarquardt','on',...
        'LineSearchType','cubicpoly','TolX',1e-10,'TolCon',1e-10);

PSI = fmincon('msecost',PSI,[],[],[],[],...
             [zeros(m,1);ones(m,1)*prctile(q,10)],...
             [inf(m,1);ones(m,1)*prctile(q,90)],[],options,...
              y,X,W,q,m);
```

From `fmincon`, i got the `fun`,`X0`,`lb`,`ub` ,the `nonlcon` and the options, my question is :

What do `y`,`X`,`W`,`q`,`m` stand for in this current code and what place it'll take in the future python function ?

Comment: `fmincon()` has been overloaded,  is `startval()` a built-in function? Check the `fmincon.m` in the directory you're running this script.

Comment: ```startval``` is a built-in function indeedd as ```msecost``` and ```setpar```

The python function would be like this :

```python```
    lb = np.concatenate([np.zeros((m,1)),np.ones((m,1))*np.percentile(q,10)])
    ub = np.concatenate([np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m,1)),np.ones((m,1))*np.percentile(q,90)])

    PSI = least_squares(fun = msecost(), x0 = PSI ,jac ='2-point',bounds =(lb,ub),method='lm',ftol=1e-10,xtol=1e-10,gtol=1e-10,max_nfev=4000)
```
Do ```y```,```X```,```W```,```q```,```m``` go into one of these parameters ```args=()```, ```kwargs={}```